# ActiveRecord relationship model with Users and Organizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find out what's the best logical way to model relationship between models. 
I have 4 models:

1. User
2. Product
3. SlackTeam
4. Organization

Here User has many Products, SlackTeams and Organizations, and SlackTeam belongs to User and has one Organization. Organization should belong to User and SlackTeam. Am I logically correct here?

The workflow is following:

- Users can log in with SlackTeam (which automatically creates Organization)
- other Users from the same slack team will be added to same Organization once they link up their account with Slack
- if Users are connected to many SlackTeams (and Organizations) they can filter to see Products from all Organizations they are part of or only from one

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  has_many :users_ogranizations
  has_many :organizations, through: :users_organizations
  has_many :products, through: :organizations
end

class Product
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization
  has_many :users_ogranizations
  has_many :users, through: :users_organizations
  has_many :products
end

class UsersOrganization
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

# i'd rather use slack profile than team, because Organization and Team 
# already connotes the same thing.
class SlackProfile

end
```

You can handle your user's login however you like, I would prefer a kind of authentication service, though. All products that belongs to the organization is now accessible to the user, you can then filter the products with:

```
current_user.products.where(organization: Organization.last)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test it out. One thing that is different from what you were proposing here is that in current db there are records where Product belongs_to User and User has_many Products. I'm thinking how this change could make the old records not working.

Comment: To clarify, your users can create product? Because my assumption here was that the Organization creates products.

Comment: Oh yes. Users actually sharing content between them as part of one organization.